# Why was this question closed and moved to SU?

Tags: discussion

I asked this question:

https://superuser.com/questions/1039154/twitter-user-profiles-dont-appear-up-when-on-some-vpns

It was closed as off-topic and moved to SuperUser.

I'm just a bit perplexed as this question is about configuring a strongswan VPN on EC2, and nothing to do with what SU seems to be about. Looking at the topic counts for the tags I chose in SF and SU, I don't see how SU would have been a more relevant forum for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question did not appear to be about managing systems in a professional, business environment. It's not a bad question, just the environment in question is off-topic on SF. Your question is worded as if you are standing up a VPN server for your own usage.

From the SF [help section](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic):

> Server Fault is for questions about managing information technology
>   systems in a business environment.

Tags alone are not enough to indicate topicality in SF or any other SE site - you must read the individual site's help section to fully understand topicality.

Comment: I see.The VPN is for a business purpose, but I am currently debugging it on my own iPhone. Perhaps the wording was poorly chosen. Thank you.